# How do I change IE8 settings for terminal (rdp) users in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, rdp, internet-explorer-8

I have a terminal server (Windows 2003) serving 10-15 users. I have a list of internet/intranet secure sites configured in administrator account for which security level is set to low.  However when a remote user logins in to a session, the settings for IE are set to default in the profile and wouldn't let the user change them.  How can I make changes to IE8 for these users and make them effective for all the RDP users?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Group policy and the ADM templates from the IE8 deployment kit.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc985341.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc985351.aspx